# Difference between $\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $\overline{\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of linear independent vector and $I$ not finite (take for example $I=\mathbb N$.

For me, $$\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}=\left\{\sum_{i\in I}a_ie_i\mid a_i\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$

So what is the difference between $\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $\overline{\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}}$ ? Indeed, if $x\in \overline{\operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}}$, then there is a sequence of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i$ s.t. $$x=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i=\sum_{i\in I}a_ie_i$$
and thus $x\in \operatorname{Span}(e_i)_{i\in I}$. So isn't it the same space ?

Comment: $\operatorname{Span}$ is an algebraic notion: its elements are *finite* linear combinations of vectors $e_i,\: i\in I$. Its closure comprises vectors which can be approached by some finite linear combinations with an arbitrary precision.

Comment: For example, in $l^2$, standard Hilbert basis spans a subspace which is dense in $l^2$, yet is properly contained in it, as for example $(1, 1/2, 1/3, ...)$ doesn't belong to such a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define the span as has been done by John in the question; that is, if we define
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\span}{Span} \span_{\text{John}}(e_i)_{i\in I} := \left\{ \sum_{i\in I} a_i e_i \ \middle|\ a_i \in \mathbb{R} \right\}, $$
then
$$ \span_{\text{John}}(e_i) = \overline{\span_{\text{John}}(e_i)}. $$
Observe that I have called this $\span_{\text{John}}$ because it is distinct from the usual definition of the span of a set of vectors, which is given by
$$ \span(e_i)_{i\in I} := \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{n} e_{i_n} \ \middle|\ a_{n} \in \mathbb{R}, i_n \in I, N \in \mathbb{N} \right\}. $$
Note the distinction: the usual span consists only of *finite* linear combinations, while John's span include *infinite* "linear combinations" as well.

If the index set $I$ happens to be finite (i.e. it has finite cardinality), then
$$ \span_{\text{John}}(e_i)_{i\in I}
= \overline{\span_{\text{John}}(e_i)_{i\in I}}
= \span(e_i)_{i\in I}
= \overline{\span(e_i)_{i\in I}}. $$
However, if $I$ has infinite cardinality, then this identity needn't hold—in particular, the span and its closure (using the usual definition) needn't agree.  For example, let $\ell^2$ be the set of all sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ which are bounded with respect to the $\ell^2$-norm, i.e.
$$ \ell^2
:= \left\{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dotsc) \ \middle|\ a_n \in \mathbb{R} \forall n, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|^2 < \infty \right\}. $$
If for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we define $e_i$ to be the sequence having a $1$ in the $i$-th place, then
$$ \ell^2 = \overline{\span(e_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}} \ne \span(e_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}. $$
I think that it is clear from the definition that each element of $\ell^2$ can be written as an infinite linear combination of the $e_i$ (for a sequence $(a_n)$, take the coefficient of $e_i$ to be $a_i$).  From this, a few technical arguments will show that
$$ \ell^2 = \overline{\span(e_i)}. $$
On the other hand, the sequence
$$ \left( 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{16}, \dotsc \right) $$
is an element of $\ell^2$, but cannot be written as a *finite* linear combination of the $e_i$, and is therefore not contained in $\span(e_i)$.

It is perhaps worth noting that the closure of the span is important in the study of Banach spaces, i.e. in functional *analysis*.  As such, it is tempting to call this set the "analytic span" of a set of vectors, rather than the "algebraic span".  I am not sure that this is standard terminology, but you would likely be understood if you used it.  It may also be worth reading up on the distinction between a [Schauder basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchauderBasis.html) and a [Hamel basis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Analysis)).

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $\operatorname{span} (e_i)_{i\in I}$ does not allow infinite linear combinations. The closure of this set contains such linear combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension is finite, then they are the same. However, in general they are not. For instance, in $C^0[0,1]$, the space of continuous, real-valued functions on $[0,1]$, there are functions (such as $e^x$) that is not in the span of the set of polynomials. However, it is in the *closure* of that span. In fact, *all* of $C^0[0,1]$ is in the closure of the set of polynomials.